# Do these integrals have a simple expression in terms of local function properties?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Recall the following identity, assuming continuity of $f$:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}f(x)}{\Delta x}=f(x_0)$$

Can similar expressions in terms of $f(x_0)$ or its derivatives be derived for the following generalization $I_n$ assuming continuity and infinite differentiability of $f$?

$$I_n = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}(x-x_0)^nf(x)}{(\Delta x)^{n+1}}$$

**COMMENT:** I highly suspect that $I_n$ is proportional to $n$-th order derivatives of $f$ evaluated at $x_0$, but haven't been able to get this using typical integration by parts.

Comment: For $n\ge 1$, isn't $I_n$ zero by applying the identity you mentioned?

Comment: The first equality is wrong. There should be a $\frac{1}{\Delta x}$ in front of the integral (plus continuity of $f$ at $x_0$.)

Comment: @EclipseSun The identity doesn’t apply (at least not directly) because you always have at least an extra power of $x^n$ multiplying $f(x)$ in the integrand, no?

Comment: That’s correct @JuliánAguirre, will make the correction promptly.

Comment: Since $x_0,n$ are constant, why can't we read $(x-x_0)^nf(x)$ as a single $f$?

Comment: That's a very good point @EclipseSun, can't believe I didn't catch that---your argument looks correct to me.

Comment: For this new $I_n$, I think you can use l'Hospital to determine the limit, as we have noted it is $\frac00$.